# how can I implement ui the same as on the image

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I am developing news app and I want to implement constrainlayout inside CardView and achieve ui the same as image below
[image: cardview image]
 but I could achieve what I want below my xml file
where I have implemented constrainlayout inside cardview

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/articleTitle"
>     tools:ignore="NotSibling" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/articleAuthor"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>     android:text="hhhhh"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />
>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/articleImageView"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/articleTitle" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/articleDescription"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>     android:text="hhhhh"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />
>
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/articleImageUrl"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/articleTitle"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
> ```

below my xml ui output from layouteditor[image: xml ui]

Comment: And what is the question/Problem here?

Comment: how can achieve the same ui on the picture

Comment: I have tried implemented all the possible solution by myself but it is not giving expected output

Comment: ok, what output is it giving you? Have you studied [the constraint layout training](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) by Google?

Comment: yes I have studied did not giving anything

Comment: I have updated my code please check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200506/discussion-between-edgar-shvedskiy-and-martin-marconcini).

Comment: I have put screenshot how it is look like now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement ui the same on the picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275035/how-to-implement-ui-the-same-on-the-picture)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to achieve is not difficult at all (although, it's hard to tell because I don't know your project).

Based upon the image you provided, here's a rough approximation using basic Constraint Layout features (no Chains, or anything too fancy); again, I don't know the exact specs and requirements, but this should serve as a starting point.

Here's how the final product looks in the Android Studio Editor, I didn't run this, so there are some artifacts not 100% correctly rendered (like the borders of the CardView), because Android Studio does an "approximation" of how it looks:

[image: This is how it looks]

#### Root Layout

You mentioned you wanted a CardView, so the root is naturally a MaterialDesign Card View:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:elevation="4dp">
```

#### Constraint Layout

Inside the card view, there's one single viewGroup: a Constraint Layout

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerRoot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white">
```

This ConstraintLayout is going to contain all the Card's contents in a flat hierarchy. It matches its parent (the card) in width, but it wraps its height, just like the Card itself.

#### Top News Header, Icon, and subtext:

THere are various ways to achieve this, and depending upon your requirements, you may want to play with vertical chains, constraining the width, etc., to avoid text from overlapping each other, and/or to enable/disable multi-line support, or ellipsis, etc. None of this information can be inferred from your static image.

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/topFlameImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="Header title"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_flash_on_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/topTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top News"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/topFlameImageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/bottomTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Editor on duty: Dan"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/topFlameImageView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/topFlameImageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topTitleTextView" />
```

Notice it's just an ImageView, and two TextViews, one below the other, all constrained together.

#### Big Image

I didn't put an image, but did add a blue background representing the image. I gave it an arbitrary height of 250dp, but this is not mandatory, you may change this; it gives you an idea.

This image is constrained to be below the above header with "Top News", etc, and it spans the whole width of the card.

```
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bigImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topFlameImageView" />
```

#### Title + Icon

Below the big image, there's what appears to be a Title (and its icon). Nothing special, just like the "header" above, an image and a text.
**Here is where there's something that I didn't do**: In your image, the text in this, aligns to the left/start, even below the icon; in this example, the TextView is constrained to the end/right of the icon, and so if it's multi-line, it will not "properly" *justify* its text to fit below the icon. In other words, in the image above, the word "Update" should be below the red "lightning bolt" icon, but it's not. (I think it looks better this way anyway... but I haven't thought how to make it look like what you exactly want). Using `drawableStart` in the TextView, doesn't give the same effect, so that's why I used a separate imageVIew for these "icons", to better control the image's placement.

```
  <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/titleImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:contentDescription="Title"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_flash_on_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bigImage" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Real Madrid provide Toni Kroos injury update"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/titleImageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/titleImageView" />
```

#### User Avatar, Name, and Timestamp (?)

This is similar to the Title, and the Header at the beginning, except you want the *timestamp* (17 m) to be at the end/right of what appears to be the user name *Onefootball*.

```
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userAvatarImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:contentDescription="Title"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleTextView" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/userNameTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Onefootball"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/userAvatarImageView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/titleImageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/userAvatarImageView" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/timestampTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:text="- 17m"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/userNameTextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/userNameTextView" />
```

One image, one Text, another text; nothing fancy.

#### Closing the tags

Last but not least, you have to close the ConstraintLayout **and** the CardView...

```
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And that's all.

#### Final Comment | Conclusion

At the beginning of this combo, I told you *StackOverflow* is not a Free Coding Site; this is still true, and I've made this effort because it seems like you are learning Android and I love helping people, but keep in mind that in general, it's *much much* better if you try firsts and come up with 20 different small questions as you go through it.

I would have personally tried to solve this in small bits (like I presented it above) and when something didn't behave as expected, it would have been easier to ask here "Hey look at this small thing, why doesn't it do X Y Z????" than to try to post the whole thing, and hope someone comes around and fixes it for you so you can copy paste the solution and forget about it.

I really hope you learn from this and don't just copy/paste it.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: thank you so much let me know if you come to sweden I am happy to provide bear

Comment: You're welcome! Same if you come to the Netherlands ;)